# Database for assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, mnemonics

I'm looking for a up-to-date database (machine readable) containing information of assembly instructions.
Capstone does some info, but it doesn't include descriptions of each instruction.

Intel's [Intel Architecture Developer's Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html) (volumes 2A and 2B) does contain it but it's isn't programmatically accessible.

Comment: Links to relevant sites (and lots of other info) are available in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info). You probably want what's under the "instruction set" part.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ and https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki are based on (different tweaks to) the same PDF-scrape script to pull info directly from Intel's vol.2 PDF (and / or their "future extensions PDF").  Specifically, https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/tree/master/VS/Python/intel-doc-2-md for the asm-dude Github.

Actually, the asm-dude repo includes AsmDudeData.xml which might be directly useful.  (Apparently "asm-dude" is a plugin for Visual Studio.  I've only looked at the repo for its wiki which includes an up-to-date html scrape including future-extensions instructions like [`ENQCMD`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/ENQCMD)

---

More of an actual database / table, **Intel's [XED](https://intelxed.github.io/) (X86 Encoder Decoder) library comes with an XML** of all instructions, including how their operands work.  It's what uops.info uses as a basis for automated microbenchmarking of every form of every instruction, plus some manual test-cases for some instructions known to have special effects.  [Uops.info's page has the current `instructions.xml` and some info about how they use it](https://uops.info/xml.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's better then nothing.

[Here's a XML](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/public/us/en/include/intrinsics-guide/data-latest.xml) It's from Intel but used in a webapp
https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide
If the link is dead, check where it gets the newer version from the page from your the network debugger in your browser